# Relation between 3 Models in Laravel 5.1 ("like many-to-many-through")

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm developing a simple Schools management app for an exam and have so far built a simple Many-To-Many relation between a **School** model and the **Field** model and of course a pivot table.

**Now I want to** relate my User model to them so that I can query for example

> **{user}** is studying **{field_of_study}** at **{school}**

At the end I want to be able to query for example

> how many users are studying at School XY or,
>
> how many are studying Field Z or,
>
> how many are studying Field Z at School XY.

Furthermore I want to be able to query all fields of study for a given school and vice versa.

My tables so far

#### Table `users`:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| Field      | Type                |
+------------+---------------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned |
| username   | varchar(60)         |
| password   | varchar(60)         |
+------------+---------------------+
```

#### Table `schools`:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| Field      | Type                |
+------------+---------------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned |
| name       | varchar(60)         |
+------------+---------------------+
```

#### Table `fields`:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| Field      | Type                |
+------------+---------------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned |
| name       | varchar(60)         |
+------------+---------------------+
```

#### Table `schools_pivot`:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| Field      | Type                |
+------------+---------------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned |
| school_id  | bigint(20)          |
| field_id   | bigint(20)          |
+------------+---------------------+
```

Unfortunatly I absolutly have no clue how to relate three Eloquent models in such a way and couldn't find any thing on the web (I probably searched for the wrong terms).

I'm pretty new to Laravel and Eloquent, so please be kind with me ;)

Comment: This may help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509088/how-can-i-display-a-table-with-two-foreign-keys-in-laravel/39509486?noredirect=1#comment66337773_39509486

Answer (score 0):

it's better to define relationship between two table and then alternately the other one.you can read this artical. maybe it will help you [three-way-pivot-table-in-eloquent](http://laravel.io/forum/08-06-2014-three-way-pivot-table-with-eloquent)

Comment: Thanks @user2480902 - I was already looking into that thread. At the end I've added another model & table which connects users, schools & fields (via `schools_pivot` table) and utilize that new relation via eager loading.