# How can i display a table with two foreign keys in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables

```
Users
-------------
user_id  (PK)
user_name

Items_distributed
-------------
user_id (FK) 
item_id(FK)

Item List
-----------------
item_id(PK)
item_name
```

Now i need to print Items_distributed table by taking both the user_id and item_id and dispaly their item_name and user_name

i dont know how to display both things at a time 
if i display either item_name or user_name its working 
but when i try to print both it is not working .
Can any one solve my problem .

This is how i print the values

in controller i use like this 
`$itemdata=item::orderBy('user_id','desc')->paginate(10);`
and in view 
i use

```
  @foreach($itemdata as $value)  
                    <tr>  
                        <td>{{$value->items->item_name}}</td>  
                        <td>{{$value->users->user_name}}</td>  
                        <td>{!!Html::link("editItem/",'Edit',array('class'=>'btn-sm  btn-warning margin-left-btn'))!!}
                            {!!Html::link("deleteItem/".$value->item_id,'Delete',array('class'=>'btn-sm btn-warning margin-left-btn'))!!}</td>
                    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Show us how you print these values.

Comment: Alter your question with this comment. It makes it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Laravel Eloquent Relationship. When you create model file for DB Table, You just put relation with other model.

If Relation has set, than Laravel it self fetch data from Related table.

In your case, Three models are created.

1) User Model.

2) Item Model.

3) ItemDestributed Model.

**UserModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Other code goes here
    **/
    public function itemDestribution()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ItemDistribution','foreign_key');
    }
}
```

**ItemModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Items extends Model
{
    /**
     * Other code goes here
    **/
    public function itemDestribution()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ItemDistribution','foreign_key');
    }
}
```

**ItemDestributionModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ItemDestribution extends Model
{
    /**
     * Other code goes here
    **/
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','foreign_key_of_user');
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item','foreign_key_of_item');
    }
}
```

You can find more about Eloquent Relation from [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: Thanks Ketav this problem is making me mad for a couple of days i'm trying alternatives to achieve the above thing i searched in google but i wont find it
finally you saved me from dead Thanks man Thank you so much.

Comment: I have small doubt i commented itemDestribution() method in both user and Item model but still it is working how?

Comment: Welcome Venkat.

Comment: Can you show me your code in which itemDestribution() is commented?

Comment: Both in UserModel.php and ItemModel.php
`public function itemDestribution()' i commented this method

Comment: post it as a new question with code.
I couldn't get your point.

Comment: Here is my Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511218/why-hasmany-relation-still-working-even-i-removed-relation-in-laravel