# Why hasMany Relation still working even i removed relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[image]

[image]
In the above both models i commented the method  itemDestribution()  but still it is working

Comment: put actual code instead of SS in question.
This is not a good way to post question.

Answer (score 0):

This relation displays a Data because of following reasons.

1. In your `ItemDestributionModel`, You have set relation with `UserModel` and `ItemModel` both.
2. In your `ItemModel` and `UserModel` you haven't declare any public function and add Relation Class.

When you call `UserModel` it will find `hasMany` Relationship in `ItemDestributionModel` and `user()` function is available with `belongsTo` relationship.

That's why laravel fetch data without declaring public function. But you should declare relationship inside public function. :)